# Can't change the nav-pills background color using Bootstrap or CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple navigation bar fixed to the top of my page which can be seen [here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/) but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the background color.  I've tried editing the a:hover code in the Bootstrap CSS files as well as overriding it in my own custom CSS file using all sorts of different class calls, but still no luck.  Can anybody help me out?  I know it has to be something simple, I'm just stumped.

Here's my HTML code for the navbar:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="index.html">Homegrown</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /.nav -->
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nav bar background is styled under `.navbar-inner`. An easy way to figure out what element has what style is to use debugging tools like chromes inspector (under view > developer > developer tools) or firebug for firefox (http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: any idea why 'a:active' doesn't work the same way as 'a:hover'?

Comment: sorry guess I misread your question, notice that the li has a class called active, you will need to change that to change the background colour: `.navbar .nav > .active > a, .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it ended up being:    .navbar .nav > .active a, .navbar .nav > .active a:hover, .navbar .nav > li a:hover {}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sass or Less, you can customize these variables from _navs.scss:

```
//== Pills
$nav-pills-border-radius:                   $border-radius-base !default;
$nav-pills-active-link-hover-bg:            $component-active-bg !default;
$nav-pills-active-link-hover-color:         $component-active-color !default;
```

You can find the corresponding less values and file.

Here's the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

However, the source is much easier to follow for this sort of customization.